# sql query to get record by multiple values

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I need a sql query that can get records from multiple table. Please check the scenario below -

There are 2 tables - Table1 and Table2

Below is the query.

Table1 :

```
PID   PName
1      A
2      B
```

Table2 : (There is a foreign key relationship b/w Table1 and Table2 by 'PID')

```
PPID   PID  RID
101     1   222
102     1   333
103     2   001
104     2   002
```

And I want query that can get records from Table1 (I need PName) and Table2 like that-

```
SELECT t1.PName FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on t1.PID = t2.PID
where t2.PID = '222' and t2.PID = '333'
```

or

```
SELECT t1.PName FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on t1.PID = t2.PID
INNER JOIN dbo.StringSplit('222,333', ',') AS t on t2.PID = t.item
```

But in both cases I am not getting the correct resutl.

I want records where PID should exists for both RID's like - 222 and 333

The output should be like this -

```
   PName 
     A
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: Please include your expected result.

Comment: What you need is not clear, please provide the desired result set as an example.

Comment: #chris,TJB , I have added my desire output.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common question. It is easy to do with grouping:

```
select min(PName) as PName
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t2.PID = t1.PID
where t2.RID in ('222', '333')
group by t1.PID
having count(*) = 2
```

Your sample data is limited and it's not clear what is the significance of the special values "111" and "222". Depending on the actual relationship you may really want a variation like `count(*) >= 2` or `count(distinct t2.RID) = 2` instead.

Btw, a few of the other answer are using a left join and then filtering on the inner table afterward in the `where` clause. In general that would be incorrect but in your case it wouldn't change your results because the outer join isn't relevant in the first place. Whichever solution you select, don't use an outer join here.

Comment: Of course if there are 2 rows where RID = '222' or '333' this will return a false positive.

Comment: @SeanLange Which is why I had the comment about `count(distinct...)`

Comment: Ahh yes missed that comment...there it is clear as day. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your first query will always return 0 results as `t2.PID` cannot equal both `222` and `333`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to include results where PID is `222` **OR** `333`. E.g.

```
SELECT t1.PName, t2.RID FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 on t1.PID = t2.PID
where t2.PID = '222' OR t2.PID = '333'
```

Comment: #Chris, I want records where PID should exists for both RID's like - 222 and 333

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.PName, t2.RID FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.PID = t2.PID
WHERE t2.RID = '222' OR t2.RID = '333'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNAME FROM dbo.Table1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ON Table11.PID = TABle22.PID
WHERE rid IN ('222','333')
```